# Automate ImageShack upload

Tags: bash, curl, imageshack

I can't figure out how to make a script to upload a picture to ImageShack, and return the hotlink of the picture in BASH, can anybody whip up one for me?  I was thinking to use curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` filename"
  exit
fi

image="$1"
mimetype=`file -b --mime-type $image`

curl -H Expect: -F "fileupload=@$image;type=$mimetype" -F xml=yes -# "http://post.imageshack.us/" | grep image_link | grep -o  http[^\<]*
```

If you don't like the progress bar, just replace `-#` with `-s`